# How to bind get_params() method to the test class?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I've designed several test classes that have fixtures sharing the same name `data`. These fixtures are parametrized with the functions `get_params` that are defined for each of these test classes separately. Note that these functions are static and are called for a class. Also note that `data` fixtures are identical.

```py
class GenericTest:
    @staticmethod
    def get_list(length):
        return range(0, length)


class Test1(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=5)

    @pytest.fixture(params=get_params())
    def data(self, request):
        return request.param


class Test2(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=10)

    @pytest.fixture(params=get_params())
    def data(self, request):
        return request.param
```

As long as these fixtures are identical, there is a temptation to move them to the base class:

```py
class GenericTest:
    @staticmethod
    def get_list(length):
        return range(0, length)

    @pytest.fixture(params=get_params())
    def data(self, request):
        return request.param


class Test1(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=5)


class Test2(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=10)
```

Now the `get_params` name is not known in the context of the `GenericTest` class. It also cannot be called with `self`, as pytest does not bind the call to any object: `@pytest.fixture(params=self.get_params())`

Is that possible to differentiate the calls to `get_params()` for different derived classes? Or what could be the workaround (other than moving the fixture back to derived classes)?

Comment: Can you show an example of tests that use those fixtures?

Comment: Does that affect the question? This example is artificial. The actual `data` is the result of `os.listdir`. There are other fixtures that depend on the `data`, and these fixtures are generic, but depend on specific `data`. The actual tests are irrelevant.

Comment: I wanted to know if that fixture would be used by more than one test or by other fixtures. That would probably make the indirect parametrization option that I suggested in the answer less attractive or even not viable.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three options.

1. Use [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) and remove the `get_params()` method:

```python
import pytest


class GenericTest():

    @staticmethod
    def get_list(length):
        return range(0, length)

    @pytest.fixture
    def data(self, request):
        return request.param


class Test1(GenericTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("data", GenericTest.get_list(5), indirect=True)
    def test_one(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 5


class Test2(GenericTest):

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("data", GenericTest.get_list(10), indirect=True)
    def test_two(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 10
```

2. You can create the `data` fixture in `Test1` and `Test2` without the `@` syntax of a decorator and remove the `get_params()` method:

```python
import pytest


class GenericTest():

    @staticmethod
    def get_list(length):
        return range(0, length)

    def data(self, request):
        return request.param


class Test1(GenericTest):
    data = pytest.fixture(params=GenericTest.get_list(5))(GenericTest.data)

    def test_one(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 5


class Test2(GenericTest):
    data = pytest.fixture(params=GenericTest.get_list(10))(GenericTest.data)

    def test_two(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 10
```

3. You can create the `data` fixture in a metaclass (and do whatever other creative things you want) while you keep the `get_params()` method of `Test1` and `Test2`:

```python
import functools

import pytest


class Meta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        if hasattr(x, "get_params") and hasattr(x, "data"):
            x.data = pytest.fixture(params=x.get_params())(x.data)
        return x


class GenericTest(metaclass=Meta):

    @staticmethod
    def get_list(length):
        return range(0, length)

    def data(self, request):
        return request.param


class Test1(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=5)

    def test_one(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 5


class Test2(GenericTest):
    get_params = functools.partial(GenericTest.get_list, length=10)

    def test_two(self, data):
        assert 0 <= data < 10
```